# Strikethrough in Jatex

Tags: support, feature-request

How do I perform a strikethrough on some text I've posted in a question ? I've tried \sout and a few others to no avail. The advanced help page in the editor doesnt provide any assistance either.

Could we potentially add how to do a strikethrough to the advanced help section in the question editor ?

Comment: What's Jatex? (I suppose one can tell from context in the answers but it would have be useful to clarify that)

Comment: Is the question _How to write [Feynman slash notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_slash_notation)?_

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to do is to include the *cancel* package into your TeX by writing the following in your code:

> \require{cancel}

After, it's relatively easy to cancel something by just writing:

> \cancel{\displaystyle\int\mathrm d^4x\,\text{whathever}}

you can also use:

> \cancelto{to whathever}{whathever}

The result:

[image: hope this helps!!!]

Comment: Nice, but what about adding this into the advanced help section of the editor or at least alluding to the idea that you can use packages in the editor (I personally didn't know the forum supported them) ? http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @AriBenCanaan Check this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Comment: Oh, okay, but I still think it's worthwhile linking that in the advanced help section of the main forum editor. Don't you ? Whenever I've been stuck (as a new member) I land up googling my issue and not always getting the right answer. I'm temporarily marking this thread as unanswered so people dont think it's dead. Also, Hakeem, how do I use @ and your name to trigger an immediate reply ? Your name is in Arabic so its making things a wee bit difficult :P

Comment: @AriBenCanaan Yes, it is. It also took me some time to be familiar with the main MathJax commands. Just copy/paste, but since you're commenting on one of my post, I immediately get a message that tells me so. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `<s></s>` for <s>striking</s> text. Not sure if there are any supported strikethrough methods in the subset of LaTeX we use here, though.

Comment: There are! See my answer.